# How to change Template ID of item Using Sitecore Api..?? Note- Only Using sitecore api

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore9

I am using sitecore Api to create and update item, my requirement is to update templateid of item using Sitecore API only in Sitecore9.0.2

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the template by it's path path after `/sitecore/template`, so for `/sitecore/templates/common/folder` template, you would need to write:

```
var yourNewTemplate = item.Database.Templates["common/folder"];
```

And then you just call `ChangeTemplate` method on your Sitecore item, e.g:

```
item.ChangeTemplate(yourNewTemplate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but there is No Sitecore connectivity with application (i.e there is no database.context all that thing's). the only thing I have i.e Sitecore Api to update or create, So I thing above code will not usefull.

Comment: The code I wrote uses **Sitecore API**, exactly as you asked in your question. I believe you may think of **Sitecore WebApi**

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any such api available which can change the template however you can edit an item using OData sitecore apis but it does not accept any such parameter which can modify it's template.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html

**Edit An Item**

URL

/item/{id}?database&language&version